# How does kernel gain control?

Tags: operating-system

As far as I know that external events such as hardware interrupts or system calls can trigger control transfer from user space to kernel space. But what if there is no external event or system calls, will the running process keep running forever?

Comment: Yes, they will.  If the kernel is not entered, it cannot do/change anything:)

Answer (score -1):

It could, but typically the kernel programs a timer device to cause an interrupt at some point in the future.  When that interrupt arrives, the kernel has the opportunity to decide what to do next.

Comment: The,OP specifically stated 'No hardware interrupts'

Comment: The, OP specifically stated "external events such as hardware interrupts"; setting aside that in virtually all modern machines the timer is a core-local cpu function; the initial phrase was "It could,", addressing the trivial notion, then providing background information on the most common mechanism used to mitigate this.